# How to remove home segment from url in typo3 4.7

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I use typo3 4.7 and i have a structure with root-page which is shortcut to a home page

now my url from domain.com appears like domain.com/home/ - how to remove the home segment
i tried with Speaking URL path segment: / but no success it appears domain.com/domain.com
and error 404
what is the right solution to this matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Remove the speaking url path segment.
2. Move all the content from the "home" page to root page.
3. Give the root page type "standard".
4. Change the "home" page to a link to the root page.

Comment: Thanks. I know that solution, the problem is that I must edit all the typoscript from root wich is aplied on subpages - but is a good solution beacause I want to keep pagerank from google on root page